# Equality of limits with respect to different metrics.

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a set equipped with two metrics, say $d_1$ and $d_2$. Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset X$ be a sequence of points which converges to $x\in  X$ with respect to metric $d_1$. Does it follow that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ either converges to $x$ with respect to $d_2$ or does not converge at all? If the answer is no, can we have some additional requirements on $d_1$ and $d_2$ for it to be the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53971/example-of-sequences-with-different-limits-for-two-norms) are example which show that even when $X$ is a normed space and the distances come from a norm, the result may not hold.

Comment: thanks, this is just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the metrics to be [*equivalent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics): you want that for each $d_2$ ball with center $x$ there exists a $d_1$ with center $x$ contained in it, and viceversa. That is, for each $\delta >0$ and $x\in X$ there exists a $\delta'>0$ such that $$B_2(x;\delta')\subseteq B_1(x;\delta)$$

and vice-versa.

---

Consider the metric space $\Bbb R$ first with the usual $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and then with the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1-[x=y]$. Here $[P]$ evaluates to $1$ when $P$ is true and to zero othewise. Then the only convergent sequences in the latter space are eventually constant ones.

Comment: if $\{x_n\}$ is convergent w.r.t. $d_1$ and not convergent w.r.t. $d_2$, then $d_1$ and $d_2$ cannot be equivalent though.

Comment: but the condition in my question allows for the metrics to be not equivalent.

Comment: @JimmyR I answered your last question. I'm thinking of the first one.

Comment: @JimmyR Yes. Equivalent metrics give rise to the same topology. In particular $\operatorname{id}:(X,d_1)\to(x,d_2)$ and $\operatorname{id}:(X,d_2)\to(x,d_1)$ are continuous. By taking the image of a sequence in either metric space the claim follows.

Comment: my last question makes sense only if the answer to my first question is no, is that the case?

Comment: @JimmyR Your last question makes sense independently of your first question. I gave you an example, hope you like it.

Comment: I see what you mean now, if norms are equivalent then of course it is case. I was hoping that there might be some weaker requirement, but I don't think it's the case.